# wicket 1.5 + error-page + cannot find the related path to css resources

Tags: java, wicket, web, web.xml

I have the next problem with wicket and standard error handling:

all the css files are stored as java resources, near the html pages.
It's working fine. But, when I added the 404 error handling in the web.xml so that any not-found-url is treating as redirect to my PageNotFound.class - the paths to css in this page are broken. it's writes it as

```
   <wicket:link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../wicket/resource/com.web.common.PageNotFound/css/common.css"/>
 </wicket:link>
```

instead of

```
 <wicket:link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wicket/resource/com.web.common.PageNotFound/css/common.css"/>
 </wicket:link>
```

(which is working fine, and appeared if I point directly to this PageNotFound page)

So the questions is - why only when error is handled it adds additional useless "../../" to css path?

I did all as it is described here (HTTP Error pages part): [adding custom error pages using wicket](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/error-pages-and-feedback-messages.html)

Comment: Can you copy the bit where you reference the CSS from your markup file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3602. This might be the cause of your problem.